# Can't execute array of methods javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, gojs

I am using `Go.js` to make a `diagram` just like one of their [sample](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dataFlow.html)
At this point, their diagram is `static` and I am trying to make it `dynamic`.
The diagram is composed of components (`template`), with `input` and `output` ports.
In the sample, to create a component you have to call the method `makeTemplate` and add specify `input` and `output` ports, like this:

```
makeTemplate(name_of_template, path_to_image, color,
                 [makePort("L", true), makePort("R", true)],//inputs
                 [makePort("UL", false), makePort("ML", false)];//outputs
```

Now, I had the initial idea to create a function that return object containing arrays with my `makePort` function calls.

```
function createPorts(input,output){
    var ports = {
        "input":[],
        "output":[],
    };
    for(var i = 0; i < input; i++)
        ports.input.push(function(){ makePort("IN"+i, true); });
    for(var i = 0; i < output; i++)
        ports.output.push(function(){ makePort("OUT"+i, true); });
    return ports
}
```

And call `makeTemplate()` method as follow:

```
makeTemplate(name, path_to_image, color,
                [],
                [createPorts(0,1).output]);
```

But I get an `error` :

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown initializer "function(){
makePort("OUT", true);}" 
for object being constructed by 
GraphObject.make: Panel(Panel.Vertical)#427
```

Comment: Why do you push a `function` to the array instead of the made port?

Comment: Because I need to pass the makePort calls later on, within the makeTemplate call. That was my initial idea to accomplish it.

Comment: No, in your original code you are passing an array of ports to `makeTemplate`, not an array of functions. So just have `createPorts` return those arrays of ports.

Comment: I was assuming that since you're calling the function makePort. You have to declare an array of function. But I think you're right, I replaced to this ports.input.push(makePort("IN"+i, true)); and it seems to work just fine